# Understanding strange behavior in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have run into something I cannot wrap my head around. It's part of a larger coding effort, but a minimal example is here:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List foo(arma::vec & tau2, const arma::vec & nu) {

  arma::vec bet = Rcpp::rnorm(3);
  tau2 = R::rgamma(1, arma::as_scalar(sum(pow(bet, 2)/nu)));

  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("nu") = nu,
                            Rcpp::Named("tau2") = tau2);
}
```

(`tau2`, although a scalar, is a vector here because I want to pass by reference: [function pass by reference in RcppArmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047145/function-pass-by-reference-in-rcpparmadillo))

What is puzzling me is that if I now run the following R code:

```
n <- 3
m <- matrix(0, n, 1)
for (r in 1:1000) {
  tau2 <- 1.0
  nu <- matrix(1, n, 1)
  upd <- foo(tau2, nu)
}
```

I get:

```
error: element-wise division: incompatible matrix dimensions: 3x1 and 18x1
Error in foo(tau2, nu) : 
  element-wise division: incompatible matrix dimensions: 3x1 and 18x1
```

where the `18x1` varies; mostly it's `0x1` but it's always a multiple of `3`.

Looking at the output:

```
> nu
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 4.165242 4.165242 4.165242 4.165242
[2,] 4.165242 4.165242 4.165242 4.165242
[3,] 4.165242 4.165242 4.165242 4.165242
> upd
$nu
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1

$tau2
         [,1]
[1,] 4.165242
```

That is, despite declaring `nu` as a constant reference (which I do because I do *not* want it changed), it is altered. The value it is filled with is `upd$tau2` (but why?).

Strangely, I can make the behavior go away by seemingly meaningless changes by:

- putting `tau2 <- 1.0` or `nu <- matrix(1, n, 1)` (or both) outside of the loop
- removing the reference in the first argument (i.e. using `arma::vec tau2`)
- not dividing `pow(bet, 2)` by `nu`
- changing to `nu <- rep(1, n)`

Perhaps the most confusing part is that if I select the code chunk inside of the loop and repeatedly run it, it works(!). However, if I run the R code using the loop it crashes on the second iteration.

Because I seem to be able to fix the problem, I'm mostly interested in learning what is going on here. I suspect it's just a consequence of my lack of expertise in C++ and recklessness with various variable types, so knowing what is causing all of this would be very valuable.

Comment: "Perhaps the most confusing part is that if I select the code chunk inside of the loop and repeatedly run it, it works(!). However, if I run the R code using the loop it crashes on the second iteration." Does it happen in the loop if you turn off JIT compilation?

Comment: You `tau2` (in R) gets overwritten inside your `foo()` -- these are (eventually) all `SEXP` which are _pointers_.  Rename, or copy `tau2` inside.

Comment: @Roland If I run `compile::enableJIT` with `0`, `1` or `2` it works.

Comment: This isn't the issue at all... The underlying cpp code is bad. In particular, the use of the `Rcpp::` generators given a `NumericVector` being _forced_ into an `arma::vec`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That's basically what I'm after. It's an MCMC sampler where `tau2` is one of the variables being updated. It's supposed to be in C++ all of it (where I guess it makes more sense), but right now when I ran into this i was just testing this updating function out from R to simplify the debugging process.

Comment: @coatless In my defense, that was actually just to make the example minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Two fixes:

1. `tau2` is a double (mimic @dirkeddelbuettel here)
2. Temporary variable for the `NumericVector` of length *n* being generated prior to saving into `bet`

Code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List foo(double tau2, const arma::vec & nu) {

  int n = nu.n_elem;

  Rcpp::NumericVector x = Rcpp::rnorm(n);
  arma::vec bet = arma::vec(x.begin(), n, true, false);

  tau2 = R::rgamma(1, arma::as_scalar(sum(pow(bet, 2) / nu)));

  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("nu") = nu,
                            Rcpp::Named("tau2") = tau2);
}
```

Test case:

```
n <- 3
m <- matrix(0, n, 1)
for (r in 1:1000) {
  tau2 <- 1.0
  nu <- matrix(1, n, 1)
  upd <- foo(tau2, nu)
}
upd
#> $nu
#>      [,1]
#> [1,]    1
#> [2,]    1
#> [3,]    1
#> 
#> $tau2
#> [1] 3.292889
```

Comment: That is admittedly a better solution. Can you offer any insights into why `nu` is modified despite not being overwritten in the C++ code and despite being a constant reference? I understand that the code is quite subpar, but it would be useful to know *why* this is happening (not just how to avoid it).

Comment: `nu` is being passed as a "reference" with `&`. Thus, it is using the _same_ memory as the object in _R_. We're doing this when we used the advanced constructor to move over the random sample draws. To keep it stationary: Remove the `&`. However, in this example, nothing changes.

Comment: I see. In my application nu is in fact fairly large so my intention was to avoid copying it (hence the &). But I guess this messes it all up.

Comment: As I just commented on Dirk's answer, I just remembered that I avoided `double` in the first place because of his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047145/function-pass-by-reference-in-rcpparmadillo I essentially just want to give the function some variables which it should update accordingly.

Comment: In the case of needing references, you can use `arma::vec& tau` and save a value into `tau2` via `tau2(0) = R::gamma(1, ...)`. In the future, consider making a bit more complete scenario.

Comment: You're right in that I should've been clear about wanting to use references from the beginning. Your suggestion illustrates the problem: changing to `tau2(0)` doesn't fix the issue (code doesn't run), but letting `tau2` be a double fixes it. I had managed to remove the problem before my post, which is why I asked about an explanation rather than a fix. As you and Dirk made quite obvious, my code isn't great. But my thinking was that if I don't understand *why* switching to `double` fixes the problem, I will probably make the same mistake again. Which would mean bothering you guys again...

Answer (score 1):

If I change the interface to using a `double` it all works:

#### Code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List foo(double & tau2, const arma::vec & nu) {

  arma::vec bet = Rcpp::rnorm(3);
  tau2 = R::rgamma(1, arma::as_scalar(sum(pow(bet, 2)/nu)));

  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("nu") = nu,
                            Rcpp::Named("tau2") = tau2);
}

/*** R
n <- 3
m <- matrix(0, n, 1)
for (r in 1:1000) {
  tau2 <- 1.0
  nu <- matrix(1, n, 1)
  upd <- foo(tau2, nu)
}
*/
```

#### Demo

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/hejseb.cpp")

R> n <- 3

R> m <- matrix(0, n, 1)

R> for (r in 1:1000) {
+   tau2 <- 1.0
+   nu <- matrix(1, n, 1)
+   upd <- foo(tau2, nu)
+ }
R> upd
$nu
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1

$tau2
[1] 1.77314

R>
```

I am not sure if those are the numbers you expected. I don't really have time to work through what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not expecting much in terms of the numbers (it's just a reprex), but what I wasn't expecting was `nu` to change when 1) it's not overwritten in the C++ code and 2) it's a constant reference. So my question was mostly about understanding what was going on.

Comment: Now I just remembered why I avoided using `double` in the first place---your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047145/function-pass-by-reference-in-rcpparmadillo I'm working on a Gibbs sampler, so `tau2` is like the current value of tau^2 in the sampler and the function in my example updates it (although obviously in the example the code is meaningless). I was so focused on this issue that I forgot to add that to my post.