# Extract every k-th column of arma::mat matrix in rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I was struggling with subsetting columns of a matrix of class arma::mat.

Let's say `arma::mat X` is given, and I tried to create a vector of indices `IDX`, in order to do `X.cols(IDX)`. Especially, the index vector has every k-th integer from 1 to p (dimension of `X`). For example, one may be interested in every even columns `IDX=[2,4,6,8, ...]`.

Based on [this documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat), contiguous indices such as [0, 1, 2, ..., m-1] can be extracted easily using `X.cols(0, m - 1)` if m <= p. However, I couldn't find a good way to subset a matrix with the index vector `IDX` described above.

I wonder how I complete this code to give a desired output.

My "subset_armamat.cpp" file looks like

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat subset_armamat(mat X, int k){
  uvec IDX = "every k-th integer from 0 to X.ncols";
  return X.cols(IDX);
}
```

and R code to execute the defined function is

```
library("Rcpp")
sourceCpp("subset_armamat.cpp")
subset_armamat(matrix(1:10, 2, 5, byrow = T), 2)
```

This is expected to produce a 2-by-3 matrix as the following R code would give

```
> matrix(1:10, 2, 5, byrow = T)[,seq(1, 5, by = 2)]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    6    8   10
```

It would be very appreciated if you give any input.

p.s. I've tried to

- generate a sequence vector `seq(1,m) * 2` manually, but this does not work with `X.cols()`.
- or find an index using `find(seq(1,p) % 2 == 0)`, but `%` operator does not work well between `seq(1,p)` and `2`.

Comment: @jogo Thanks to your advice, I updated my question. However, I couldn't find `seq.int` function in rcpp, but `seq` only. Would you give me more details to use that function?

Comment: it is a function from `R` (package `base`)

Comment: @jogo Ah, that one. Then, can I save it to a arma::uvec? To put it in `.cols()`, it should be uvec type, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[F. Privé's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52850444/8386140) showed that you can in fact use a `uvec` to subset a matrix using `.cols()` even if its not a contiguous range, using the base R `seq()` function to generate the sequence. I will further demonstrate that you can generate the sequence using an Armadillo function; you can use `arma::regspace()` -- it "generate[s] a vector with regularly spaced elements" ([Armadillo documentation source](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#regspace)):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat subset_armamat(mat X, int k) {
    uvec IDX = regspace<uvec>(0,  k,  X.n_cols-1);
    return X.cols(IDX);
}
```

As a comparison to calling R's `seq()` (where `subset_armamatR()` is the function from F. Privé's answer):

```r
library("Rcpp")
sourceCpp("subset_armamat.cpp")
mat <- matrix(1:10, 2, 5, byrow = TRUE)
subset_armamat(mat, 2)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    3    5
#> [2,]    6    8   10
subset_armamatR(mat, 2)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    3    5
#> [2,]    6    8   10
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Rseq = subset_armamatR(mat, 2),
               regspace = subset_armamat(mat, 2))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#>      Rseq 235.535 239.1615 291.1954 241.9850 248.6005  4704.467   100   a
#>  regspace  14.221  15.0225 520.9235  15.8165  16.6740 50408.375   100   a
```

#### Update: Passing by reference

A comment from [hbrerkere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3928744/hbrerkere) warrants some brief additional discussion. If you are calling this function from C++, you'll gain speed by changing `mat subset_armamat(mat X, int k)` to `mat subset_armamat(const mat& X, int k)`. Passing by reference like this avoids an unnecessary copy, and when you do not intend to change an object passed by reference, you should use `const`. However, if you are calling this function from R, you cannot avoid a copy as `arma::mat` is not a native R type (see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44047685/8386140) by [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) (the maintainer of both [`Rcpp`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rcpp) and [`RcppArmadillo`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo)). Consider the following example:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void reference_example(arma::mat& X) {
    X(0, 0) = 42;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_reference_example(arma::mat X) {
    reference_example(X);
    Rcpp::Rcout << X << "\n";
}
```

Then calling from R:

```r
library("Rcpp")
sourceCpp("reference_example.cpp")
mat <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
mat
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    3
#> [2,]    2    4
reference_example(mat)
mat
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    3
#> [2,]    2    4
print_reference_example(mat)
#>    42.0000    3.0000
#>     2.0000    4.0000
mat
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    3
#> [2,]    2    4
```

Comment: wow. It's like I was wandering to find this answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: To get more speed, change `mat subset_armamat(mat X, int k)` to `mat subset_armamat(const mat& X, int k)`. This will avoid creating an (unnecessary) copy of X inside the subset_armamat function.

Comment: @hbrerkere I have added some discussion of this issue. You're right assuming OP is calling this function *from C++* (which I'm assuming will be the case), but **not** if OP is calling it *from R* (see updates for explanation), which is why I didn't include such a function in my benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat subset_armamat(mat X, int k) {

  // Obtain environment containing function
  Rcpp::Environment base("package:base"); 

  // Make function callable from C++
  Rcpp::Function seq = base["seq"];    

  uvec IDX = as<uvec>(seq(0, X.n_cols, k));
  return X.cols(IDX);
}
```

I just call R function `base::seq()` from Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks, F. Prive. Would you mind let me know what type the output of `base::seq()` is? Also, do you happen to know if there is a way not to call R function?

Comment: You do not need to go to R to create a sequence.